# How to prevent scheduler jobs from running at instance startup

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm currently testing Oracle 11g restore procedures from RMAN backups. I can restore instances to another host, but problem I'm having is that as soon as I open the restored instance, scheduler jobs start immediately.

I can disable scheduler by running:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('SCHEDULER_DISABLED','TRUE');
```

But I can't do this until after instance has started.

Is there a way to disable jobs before starting up the instance?

Comment: Another option is a `AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE` trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the job_queue_processes parameter to 0 before opening the database.

Comment: works from 11gR2. Before that, job_queue_processes = 0 did not help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the exact version. From 11gR2 we can use job_queue_processes = 0 to prevent any job from running.

Before 11gR2 you could use services for that. To use services make the job classes that you want to use depend from a service that is controlled using the instance parameters and leave it out when starting the service.

Answer (score 2):

This works at least since 10.1:

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
... disable the unneeded DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs here...
... don't forget DBMS_JOB jobs ...
ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
```